# ElasticSearch error request params: "wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, efk

I am facing error

```
"Readiness probe failed: Waiting for elasticsearch cluster to become ready (request params: "wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s" )

    Cluster is not yet ready (request params: "wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s" )" in Elasticsearch pods as soon as Kibana is installed in EKS cluster.
```

This is how I installed,

```
Elastic search:
helm install elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch -f elasticsearch/values.yaml

elasticsearch/values.yaml
# Shrink default JVM heap.
esJavaOpts: "-Xmx128m -Xms128m"

# Allocate smaller chunks of memory per pod.
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "100m"
    memory: "512M"
  limits:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "512M"
# Request smaller persistent volumes.
volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  storageClassName: "gp2"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100M
```

Kibana installation:

```
helm install kibana elastic/kibana
```

I am just using the default values mostly from helm charts.
Any idea why ElasticSearch goes down as soon as Kibana is installed?

Kibana is showing 0/1 for Pod Readiness showing Http response 000 expected 200 I think its because ElasticSearch is going down.

Answer (score 0):

I used `wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=50s` as `clusterHealthCheckParams` along with `initialDelaySeconds` set to `120` under `readinessProbe`.

It worked.

Reference: [Elastic Docs > Elasticsearch Guide [8.7] > REST APIs > Cluster APIs > Description](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html#cluster-health-api-desc)